# How can Yii Relational Query's provide an aggregation broken-down by category?

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, yii, aggregate-functions

I have a `Person` that can receive many types of `Income`. I want to be able to return the `SUM` income earned, broken down by each `Income Type`.

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| INCOME TYPE   | SUM AMOUNT      |
+---------------+-----------------+
| Salary        | $934.33         |
| Gambling      |  $27.99         |
| Tips          | $584.00         |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

I've been able to get a `self::STAT` relational query to provide the overall Income received ($1546.32), but not broken-down by `Income Type`.

As a result, I'm trying to do it as a `self::HAS_MANY` relational query within the `Person` model, like so:

```
  public function relations() {
     return array(
        'incomes_total' => array(
           self::HAS_MANY,
           'Income',
           'person_id',
           'select' => array('income_type_id', 'SUM(amount) AS total'),
           'group' => "income_type_id"
     ));
  }
```

This results in the following SQL being generated:

```
SELECT
  "incomes_total"."income_type_id" AS "t1_c5"
, SUM(amount) AS total
, "incomes_total"."id" AS "t1_c0"
FROM "stwd_income" "incomes_total"
WHERE ("incomes_total"."person_id"=:ypl0)
GROUP BY income_type_id
```

This gets very close to the query needed.

What I can't figure out is why the line `, "incomes_total"."id" AS "t1_c0"` has been added in there. I don't want that. It's causing a `CDbException` error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: 
SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "incomes_total.id" must 
appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.
```

How can I achieve the type of query that I need to?

**UPDATE 1:** The difference between Active Record and custom SQL queries is starting to become clear, and that Active Record may not be appropriate for such a task.

Comment: Did u tried  `'select' => array('income_type_id', 'SUM(incomes_total.amount) AS total'),`

Comment: @dInGd0nG I just did based on your suggestion. It gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't use ActiveRecord for anything else than very basic queries and CRUD. Even if STAT relations exist they are better used for simple counts or sums. And a HAS_MANY relationship is wrong in any way as you are not expecting an array of models, are you? You only want a simple array of ids and sums, so in your case I would simply create a method in the Person model like this

```
private $_salaryInfo;

public function getSalaryInfo()
{
    //cache the value if possible to save unnecessary queries
    if(isset($this->_salaryInfo))
        return $this->_salaryInfo;

    //query database
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
    $command->select('income_type_id, SUM(amount)')->where('person_id = '.$this->id)->groupBy('income_type_id');
    return $this->_salaryInfo = $command->queryAll();
}
```

You should now be able to do

```
foreach($person->salaryInfo as $type_id => $sum)
```